# Multiple random numbers in assembly x86 [DOS-TASM]

Tags: assembly, random, x86, dos, tasm

So I need a random number generator for my school project but I couldn't find one that gets multiple numbers, just a single one each time

this is the best one I found so far but unfortunately this is not quite what I need:

```
   MOV AH, 00h       
   INT 1AH     
   mov  ax, dx
   xor  dx, dx
   mov  cx, 10    
   div  cx
   add  dl, '0'
   mov ah, 2h
   int 21h
```

I understood it is something with "pseudo-random" but I didn't fully understand

Any ideas?